# jQuery AJAX call - how to keep comments

Tags: jquery, ajax

**context:** For the development version of a JavaScript project I wrote a small utility to keep track of scriptfile dependencies (because I don't like any of the existing libraries' hilarious syntax requirements). I wanted to make it work in a way similar to other languages, so I decided to parse imported files for comments like this:

```
// DEPENDS: myurl.js //
```

to build and evaluate dependency graphs and fetch dependencies using jQuery's $.ajax(). This works well with top-level files. Files loeded with the ajax-call, however, get stripped of comments, so I can not parse the dependencies further.

For your interest: The cycle is

1. fetch file
2. parse content with regex for dependencies
3. extend dependency graph if neccessary
4. start from (1), if (3) happened (with required files, of course)
5. evaluate files' script content in order

**question:** Is there a way to stop jQuery from removing JavaScript comment tags from files loaded by $.ajax()?

**code:** I am calling ajax this way

```
$.ajax({
  url: fileName,
  dataType: 'text',
  context: this,
  success: function(jqXHR) {
    this.parseImport(fileName, jqXHR);
  }
});
```

(from inside a method providing *fileName* and *this* properly). I was hoping *dataType: 'text'* would force jQuery to import text literally, but, well, it didn't :-D

The API document for $.ajax() tells, that the content of *dataType: text* elements gets parsed with *window.String*, but I'm not sure, what *window.String* does to its input. Maybe the solution is somewhere in this part?

I'd be glad if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Side note: `jqXHR` is a ***very*** strange name for the argument to the success function, which isn't a `jqXHR` object.

Comment: Well... ack ;) It's a leave from an approach that passed a jqXHR response object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're using `ajax` will not strip comments from the file. You're asking jQuery to load text from the server. It will load that text, faithfully, without modifying it in any way. I suspect you have some minification/compression process in place at the *server* end that removes comments. That jQuery code won't.

But you can still get around whatever it is that's removing comments — by not using comments. You can use a string instead:

```
"DEPENDS: myurl.js";
```

Since that's not a comment, it shouldn't get stripped. It looks a bit odd at first, but JavaScript's syntax has *ExpressionStatement*, which is a statement consisting entirely of an expression. And of course, a string literal on its own is a valid expression. (This is how they did `"use strict";` in ES5 without it causing a problem for pre-ES5 JavaScript engines.)

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. It will also fix the problem of tags getting stripped when files get compiled/minimised (although compiling should remove the need for the dependency graph anyways). I'll check your thesis of server-side problems and implement your suggestion right away...

Comment: I tested your solution and checked the files locally and on different server softwares. As expected, embedding the DEPENDS... in a string worked. Also, there was no string-reformatting on jQuery's side, but the minimal server (*mongoose*) didn't update timestamps, so the browser used cached file versions without the required comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with string is a good one, but I really believe there is a another good solution.

Just define your ajax engine e.g. "myscript" with `ajaxTransport`. E.g. see [this link](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/blob/master/BinaryTransport/jquery.binarytransport.js): you can register your method which will return everything in the way you like; furthermore: you can parse the comments directly in the transport and return dependencies as an array.

That will encapsulate your parsing methods and build them into ajax call like it was your own JavaScript file standard.

To learn more (actually they have a lack of examples there) see [see jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/)

Comment: jQuery wasn't the thing stripping the comments, so no need for a custom engine. (In fact, it turned out nothing was stripping the comments.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _turned out?_ so why he didn't see the comment ? I couldn't find it in this post :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It was [this comment from the OP on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095685/jquery-ajax-call-how-to-keep-comments/30096326?noredirect=1#comment48304496_30095747): *"there was no string-reformatting on jQuery's side, but the minimal server (mongoose) didn't update timestamps, so the browser used cached file versions without the required comments"*